# AppStore / Market : migrate existing user base

Tags: android, ios, migration, app-store, google-play

In recent talk with client, we got an interesting question, if we are able to release new version of application to current users.

We can get certificates for Android Market / App Store, to release application with same signature, but previous supplier is a business enemy, so we want to migrate all users they currently have on the application to our version, via standard update mechanism.

Is this possible? To migrate application to another developer/publisher account and to release an update (which can be completely different, from previous version) so that iTunes/Market update will download and install the new version instead?

I'm looking for solution on both platforms Android Market and Apple App Store, even if it would be necessary to pay some fees and so.

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Comment: @Abizern offer me better place to ask

Comment: It isn't up to me to find a better place for it, that's for you. I can only say that I think this is not the place for it. As for iOS app - you'll need to have the app's bundle id allocated to your developer account. If you don't have that you have no control over the current app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer for the Android Market:
If you have the release-keys of your old application, you can develop a new application, sign the application with the old key and everybody will be able to upgrade. Of course it will be your job to read the old data, which is saved on the device and transform it to a format which your new app can read, but thats a implementation issue. You will also need access to the google account which was used to upload the application. Google can transfer the account ownership on request.

So: **If you got the release-keys, its possible on Android.** Otherwise, I'm quite sure that you wont find a solution, you can not upgrade applications if the old and the new version are signed with different keys.

Comment: oh, great news for android, I hope somebody will talk in the same way of iOS in this thread. Thanks @theomega

Answer (score 1):

(For android) I have not done this, but without Google's intervention, it would require access to the key that was used to sign the app and the android market account that was used to load the app. If you have those two things, it is possible. Without those, you will probably have to create a new app.

Comment: problem is, I want to migrate this app to another account, so it won't belong to previous publisher. Is it possible?

Comment: The release key is tied to the developer account. If you're going to be changing the apps release key (because you are changing developer accounts) the only possible way I can see is by contacting google.